# "give me an offer" vs "make me an offer"

Tags: differences

Which is correct: "give me an offer" vs. "make me an offer"?

Is there some difference in meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Make me an offer" is more idiomatic. But you might also say "Give me a quote" or "Give me a price", if you were buying something.

Answer (score 1):

> Which is correct: "give me an offer" vs. "make me an offer"?

They are both correct phrases.

Comment: @Shinto sherlock: but I think that "give me an offer" gives the feeling that the offers are stacked at the seller and you are asking him to give you one, and "make me an offer" gives the feeling that the seller is allowed to negociate the prices with the customers.

Comment: I think `make me an offer` has connotations to Godfather, the movie.